# Chrome: How to get ajax request to work with kerberos if not already authenticated

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, kerberos

We have a REST API secured using Kerberos.  Hosted elsewhere is a webapp that calls this API.

If you navigate directly to the API, then the authentication works fine and a cookie is returned.  Then the webapp works just fine since it has a cookie for API's root URI.

However if you navigate to the webapp and it makes an `HTTP GET` request to the API using AJAX, then the request returns `401: Unauthorized` as well as `WWW-Authenticate:Negotiate`.  If I navigate to the same address, chrome would negotiate and get authenticated, but in this case it stops at this point.

There are various ugly hacks to get around the problem, like creating an IFRAME that sources some part of the API, or redirecting the user to the API and having it bounce the user back using a 307, but these are clearly not optimal.

It works fine in IE7.

What is the correct way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue.  The REST API had an additional authentication layer that used the "Authorization" http header to set an api-key.  After removing this security layer, everything worked fine.

I'm going to leave this question up in case anybody else makes the same mistake.

Comment: What do you actually mean with "after clearing the API from the authorization header"? I'm having a similar issue. Using chrome to browse to https://secure.domain/api i'm logged in successfully using kerberos but when i load this from https://www.otherdomain/webapp using jQuery's `.ajax` i get an `401 Authorization required`. I've got the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers covered i think, but now Chrome won't automatically log in. How would your solution apply?

Comment: I updated the answer.  My problem was due to a custom authentication layer that used an API key.  Getting rid of that layer fixed the problem.  Sounds like you are having a different problem.

Comment: How did you get rid of that layer? Did you add a new jquery ajax header with Authorization null (to clear it out)?

Comment: The extra layer was hooked into Spring.  Basically it was just an accident since we were trying to use the "Authorization" http header twice for two different purposes (apiKey vs kerberos).