# How to set up a connection with Kerberos in Python application?

Tags: python, flask, django-rest-framework, active-directory, kerberos

I have task to create `SSO` (single sign-on) authorization in `Python` backend application with the help of `Kerberos` and `Active Directory`.

In other words, frontend application make AJAX GET request of the specific URL of the backend application. That backend application must return information about employee in JSON format.

What I have done so far:

1) `SPN` name for the backend application was created in `Active Directory`.

2) `krb5.keytab` file for the backend application was created.

3) Active Directory and Kerberos server located on remote Windows server.

4) Backend application would be in Linux Docker container.

5) I install Kerberos client to Docker container.

6) Kerberos Realm: `SERVICE.LOCAL`.

7) Hostname for the KDC Server: `CS001, CS002, CS003`.

Have you ever seen any implementations of the above process in Python? I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 ways to handle this:

1. Handle it directly in Python
2. Handle it in a proxy such as apache or nginx

**Pure Python Solution**

If you don't have a proxy or just want to handle it in python anyway, I recommend using the [python-gssapi library](https://github.com/pythongssapi/python-gssapi). [Here's a code sample](https://gist.github.com/DirectXMan12/3f36666c26f0df4e024f). There are other Python bindings but from my reading, this one seems to be the most complete.

Note, if you handle it this way, your python server will probably need to be able to respect the keep-alive header (i.e. re-use the same connection for multiple requests). This isn't strictly part of the SPENGO protocol, but most browsers seem to require that the server implements it.

**Proxy Solution**

If you're using apache, there's a [mod_auth_kerb](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/) module you can use which is well documented. There's also a [mod_auth_gssapi](https://github.com/modauthgssapi/mod_auth_gssapi) which provides similar functionality.

For nginx, there's [a similar module](https://github.com/stnoonan/spnego-http-auth-nginx-module) available.

With any of these proxy solutions, the idea is that the proxy handles Kerberos auth, and sets the **REMOTE_USER** env variable for your python app. So your python app needs to be able to accept this variable as an authenticated user. **Django** has middleware specifically for that purpose - I'm not sure about **Flask** (I mention these 2 frameworks because they're in your question's tags).

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I have another question. Will the first solution which you recommended work in case the requests are coming from the frontend app and not from the browser? Users will interact through the frontend app in my case. As I know browser should just be reading the credential cache on the machine of employee, in the same time I don't think we can send all credential cache through axios (ajax) request from frontend application to backend application. I am little bit confused in this part.

Comment: The situation which I described in the previous comment is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869357/chrome-how-to-get-ajax-request-to-work-with-kerberos-if-not-already-authenticat) I think.

Comment: Sorry I read "AJAX" and assumed "browser". The server side solution would be the same regardless of whether the request is from a browser or something else. But it looks like you need to find out how to interact with the Kerberos client libraries from Axios. I don't know much about this I'm afraid. Basically you need a way to generate a base64 token from the client credentials, and then send this token in the Authenticate header. python-gssapi has examples of how to do it in python - that should illustrate what needs to happen. Then you need to find out how to do the equivalent in Axios.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098912/kerberos-authentication-in-node-js-https-get-or-https-request